# C++ frontend only compiler (convert C++ to C)

Tags: c++, c, embedded, cross-platform

I'm currently managing some C++ code that runs on multiple platforms from a single source tree (Win32, Linux, Verifone CC terminals, MBED and even the Nintendo GBA/DS). However I need to build an app targetted at an embedded platform for which there is no C++ compiler (C only). I remmber that many of the early C++ compilers were only front-ends stitting on existing C compilers (Glockenspiel for example used MSC). Are there any such 'frontend' C++ compilers in use today that will generate C code.

```
                      Tools            Platform
                      -----------      ------------

                ______Visual C++ _____ WIN32
               /
              /_______MBED (ARM)_______MBED (ARM dev board).
             /
            /_________GCC (x86)________Linux
           /
Source____/___________GCC (ARM)________GBA/DS
          \
           \__________SDA______________Verifone Verix CC Terminals
            \
             \________ARM SDT__________Verifine VerixV CC terminals
              \
               \______????_____________Renases M8/16/32.
                \
                 \____????_____________Z8 family.
```

The last two platforms I have good C compilers for but no C++.

As you can see I'm supporting a large variety of platforms and I share a large body of library code (and some app code).

Comment: A couple of good things to check out, in particular LLVM as a means of generating C from C++ plus I hadn't realised that GCC now supports the Renesas M16/M32 (that only leaves the Z8 without a C++ compiler and to be honest I just bought a cheap dev board to check it out, nostalgia for my Z80 origins, it is a nice microcontroller though). Also I would like to target older Hypercom terminals (I have written a good bit of code for these but I have to have a separate source tree. I know the latest Hypercoms are ARM based but there are still millions of those pesky ICE terminals out there.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/737257

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If you use [LLVM](http://llvm.org/), [`llvm-g++`](http://llvm.org/releases/2.4/docs/CommandGuide/html/llvmgxx.html) will compile your C++ code to LLVM bitcode, and [`llc`](http://llvm.org/releases/2.6/docs/CommandGuide/html/llc.html) has a backend which converts bitcode to C.

You could write commands like this:

```
llvm-g++ -emit-llvm -c foo.cpp -o foo.o
llc -march=c <foo.o >foo.c
```

Comment: Your second link is broken.

Comment: The C backend was [removed in LLVM 3.1](http://releases.llvm.org/3.1/docs/ReleaseNotes.html#changes): "It had numerous problems, to the point of not being able to compile any nontrivial program."

Answer (score 18):

[Comeau C++](http://www.comeaucomputing.com/) does this.

Comment: Was going to say the same but you beat me to it by 11 seconds

Comment: I think I've come across this compiler before. The only iussue is that the problem platform are for hobby use only. As far as I can recollect the Comeau compiler is a tad expensive.

I'm using the ARM SDT for work (expensive but the job pays).
I also use Visual Studio 2008 at work (again paid for by work).
I used Visual Studio Express at home.

Comment: Wow, it's "breathtaking," "amazing," "fabulous," and they even have a blinking javascript link that floats on top of the text urging you to purchase it!

Comment: @Seth: the web site is a bit overboard, but it *is* the best C++ compiler around, at least in terms of conformance.

Comment: @JudgeDread: at least the normal Windows version of Comeau C++ is decidedly inexpensive -- $50US/copy. I'm not sure what they charge to port it to other targets though.

Comment: @JudgeDread: you should ask Comeau about pricing - for the more popular platforms (or at least Windows & Linux) it's $50.  If he already has a port for the target you're looking for, maybe it'll be the same.  But for a custom port it'll likely not (this page, http://www.comeaucomputing.com/custom.html, indicates $5K - $50K). But it can't hurt to ask - worst case, you're no better off than right now.

Comment: @Seth - the site is quite a sight. And if you decide to buy, the order page is pretty fun too.

Comment: The site is dead now unfortunately.  COHERENT is based on Comeau, so there might be an opportunity there, but I haven't explored it.  https://www.autometer.de/unix4fun/coherent/#inst_coh

Answer (score 5):

Can't help with the Z8, but the Renesas M16C/M32C family has GCC these days - see http://www.kpitgnutools.com/ for prebuilt cross toolchain hosted on Windows. Haven't used it myself yet but may be a better option than a 3rd party C++ frontend, especially as your code already targets GCC on other platforms.

Comment: Thanks, will check it out (I'm currrently using the Glyn dev boards for R8 & R32, from Elektor, a European electronics mag). The dev kits are handy as they're on little DIL boards, makes it easy to use on breadboards and they can then be plugged into SIL/DIL sockets on homemade PCBs. The MBED I;m using has a similar form factor.

Answer (score 2):

Comeau C++ generates C as its output, and they seem to be quite happy to port it to work with different back-end compilers, though I'm not sure about the exact pricing for that.

If you want a bit more of  a "roll your own" approach, you could buy a license to the EDG C++ compiler. It's normally used as a front-end (e.g. by Comeau and Intel) but I believe as it's shipped, it includes a code generator that produces C as its output. Its licensing is oriented more toward compiler vendors, though, so a license gives you a lot of rights, but is pretty expensive.

Answer (score 1):

Out of date, but maybe you want to try [cfront](http://www.softwarepreservation.org/projects/c_plus_plus/cfront)?

I'll leave this for information - cfront doesn't have exception support.

Answer (score 1):

Of what I have understood, the c++ support in gcc for r8c/m16c/r32c isn't quite mature and good enough for production code. But for r8c/m16c/m32c/r32c there is at least one compiler supporting embedded C++ and that is IAR, I think Tasking also supports embedded C++ on m16c.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the valid solution is for llvm **1.3**
llvm last release was **6.0.0** so it would'nt work at all.
(I post this because i've try the solution of this post but it doesn't work anymore) (Maybe i've done something bad)

In my tests **llc do not accept** anymore the **-march=c** option.
And going back to the **1.3** isn't possible for me yet.
So try to take care about the version.