# Is there a way to compile C++ to C Code?

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, compiler-theory

I have a program which is configured by the user by using C++ classes and
the same class should be used to configure a program which
can only use a subset of C99 (Open CL Language).

So my question is:
Is there a way to compile C++ to C-Code?

Open Source would be great!

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ to C conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706561/c-to-c-conversion)

Comment: Also beware that there's a difference between converting a snippet like a single class, and compiling a whole C++ program with C source as the target. Some of the tools mentioned in the answers below won't give you a way to actually *call* your configuration class (written in C++ and converted to possibly-unreadable C) from your C program, or at least not to do so easily. If the process exports the C++ functions at all then they will have mangled names, as the first obstacle.

Comment: The usual way to make some C++ code callable from your C code *isn't* to convert it to C. Instead you put a wrapper API around the C++ code, consisting of `extern "C"` functions, then you compile it with a C++ compiler that produces object files compatible with the same linker used by your C compiler, and link everything together. Conversion would be a last resort if your platform doesn't provide compatible C and C++ compilers (most likely reason I suppose being that it doesn't provide a C++ compiler/runtime at all).

Comment: In case of my problem, I am merely dealing with simple classes without inheritance and I am working with Open CL C plattform [link](http://www.khronos.org/opencl/) which is thought for graphics cards and so on and I don't get a C++ compiler. My problem is that CUDA supports C++ partly and my program shall complete a software sweet so that it would be great to specify the source as c++ class instead of doing twice the work which would be error-prone.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ frontend only compiler (convert C++ to C).](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833484/c-frontend-only-compiler-convert-c-to-c)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert C++ Code to C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/737257/how-to-convert-c-code-to-c)

Comment: OpenCL 2.2 now supports C++ kernels. https://www.khronos.org/news/press/khronos-releases-opencl-2.2-provisional-spec-opencl-c-kernel-language

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The C++ FAQ has a list of possibilities: [Is it possible to convert C++ to C?](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/compiler-dependencies#convert-to-c).

In short, it says that you can't expect this to give you particularly readable code.  Think of the complexities involved; multiple inheritance, virtual-function resolution, templates, operator overloading, etc., etc.  There's no <s>clean</s> succinct way of expressing these concepts in pure C.  If all you're after is compilable C, though, then this is probably the way to go.

Comment: Actually, nothing you list is terribly difficult to implement in portable, pure C – though it can be verbose.  When you have MI, however, pointers to member functions and pointers to data members are harder (in portable, pure C).

Comment: @Fred: I don't claim that these are *difficult* to implement, but they are extremely *tedious* to implement!  But yes, you're right; the main obstacle is verbosity.

Comment: For example, struct A : B, C {}; becomes struct A { struct B __base_subobject_1; struct C __base_subobject_2; };.  Virtual function resolution can happen through a vtable, which is just an array of function pointers (most people are familiar with this).  Templates could work by instantiating them exactly as C++ requires, using names like \_\_vector\_\_int for vector<int>.  Operator overloading can simply be a named function: __SomeType_add for a + b; since you resolve the overload in C++, you know exactly what the C calls.

Comment: Ah, I must have misread it as "complexities... There's no clean way of expressing these concepts in pure C."  There are clean ways for those listed!

Comment: @Fred: I've slightly modified the wording in my answer!

Answer (score 23):

You could use the [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) C++ frontend to generate llvm bytecode, and use `llc` to emit C code, see [llc doc](http://llvm.org/releases/1.3/docs/CommandGuide/html/llc.html), especially the `c` option. Both are open source, with BSD like licenses.

Comment: If the resulting code doesn't need to do anything except build, this migh be the best choice. Don't expect `llc`'s output to be anywhere readable code.

Comment: Yeah. Very readable ^^. I think for my purpose the code would be too fat. The software is to going to run on a graphics card later (language Open CL C) and everyone wants to have small, efficient code.

Comment: @cl_progger: if you want small, efficient, readable C code then I think the best thing to do is to write it in C. OK, so CUDA would permit you to use C++ for what you want, but if OpenCL doesn't and the same configuration code needs to work on both... Not everything in the world needs to be a class, does it? ;-)

Comment: That's true. Unfortunately the program for CUDA exists and there are classes for that program... Perhaps converting C to C++ is easier?

Comment: Just for note. `llc -c` option seems to be deprecated. [The manual](http://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/llc.html) doesn't mention about it anymore.

Comment: It's considered buggy and no one wants to maintain it (at least that's the reason for its deprecation)

Comment: A fork of llvm with the C backend retained is now at https://github.com/JuliaComputing/llvm-cbe

Answer (score 10):

The Comeau compiler seems to be able to do that. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comeau_C/C%2B%2B) "Rather than produce an executable directly, Comeau C/C++ outputs C code and requires a separate C compiler in order to produce the final program."

I have never tried it, though.

Comment: Comeau works as described.  It tailors the C output for the specific backend compiler with knowledge of how each backend compiler optimizes code.

Answer (score 5):

1. VisualGBD is a Visual Studio extension that allows you to develop in compile for embedded platforms.  It's not free but there is a trial.  Worth it in my mind if it works for your application.

   https://visualgdb.com
2. LLVM <strike>is</strike> was a good option but it's been discontinued. (The C backend has been resurrected [here](https://github.com/JuliaHubOSS/llvm-cbe), and *may* make the following instructions work)

   <strike>http://llvm.org/docs/FAQ.html#translatecxx</strike>

   It handles some code, but will fail for more complex implementations
   as it hasn't been fully updated for some of the modern C++
   conventions. So try compiling your code frequently until you get a
   feel for what's allowed.

   Usage sytax from the command line is as follows for version 9.0.1:

   ```
   clang -c CPPtoC.cpp -o CPPtoC.bc -emit-llvm
   clang -march=c CPPtoC.bc -o CPPtoC.c
   ```

   For older versions (unsure of transition version), use the following
   syntax:

   ```
   llvm-g++ -c CPPtoC.cp -o CPPtoC.bc -emit-llvm
   llc -march=c CPPtoC.bc -o CPPtoC.c
   ```

   Note that it creates a GNU flavor of C and not true ANSI C. You will
   want to test that this is useful for you before you invest too
   heavily in your code. For example, some embedded systems only accept
   ANSI C.

   Also note that it generates functional but fairly unreadable code. I
   recommend commenting and maintain your C++ code and not worrying
   about the final C code.
3. The Comeau site is dead unfortunately.  Coherent is built on comeau
   and might offer some options.  They have prebuilt VMs which have
   been maintained as recent as 2018.

   https://www.autometer.de/unix4fun/coherent/#inst_coh
4. Cfront is available but has not been updated in a long time

   http://www.softwarepreservation.org/projects/c_plus_plus/cfront/release_3.0.3/source/cfront_3_0_3.tgz

Comment: llvm appears to have removed the c backend so isn't available out of the box on recent release, but it appears to have been resurrected here: https://github.com/JuliaHubOSS/llvm-cbe

Answer (score 2):

1. Comeau Computing offers a compiler based on Edison Design Group's front end that outputs C code.
2. LLVM is a downloadable compiler that emits C code. See also here and here. Here is an example of C++ to C conversion via LLVM.
3. Cfront, the original implementation of C++, done by Bjarne Stroustrup and others at AT&T, generates C code. However it has two problems: it's been difficult to obtain a license since the mid 90s when it started going through a maze of ownership changes, and development ceased at that same time and so it doesn't get bug fixes and doesn't support any of the newer language features (e.g., exceptions, namespaces, RTTI, member templates).
4. Contrary to popular myth, as of this writing there is no version of g++ that translates C++ to C. Such a thing seems to be doable, but I am not aware that anyone has actually done it (yet).

http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/users/yechiel/c++-faq/convert-to-c.html