# producing c code from c++

Tags: c++, c, console, g++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Code convert from C++ to C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737257/code-convert-from-c-to-c)

Two months ago, my instructor have asked one question, I have searched to looking for answer but I could not find it.

question :

```
   From c++ code, how can one  generate c code just using console ( with g++ ) .
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: First generation C++ compiler used to do this..when C++ was simple..

Comment: This might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/737257/code-convert-from-c-to-c

Comment: @leppie, to prevent cheating in homework

Comment: @leppie For compatibility with C applications?

Comment: None of those are valid answers. @Lundin: There are tools that does this, CORBA and SWIG come to mind.

Comment: Is the question about converting C++ code to C, or about dynamically generating C code from a C++ program and feeding that to the compiler?

Comment: CORBA generates code from idl files, not from C++. SWIG I know of as a tool for integrating C++ with Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

g++ compiles C++ directly to machine code, it does not first compile to C then compile that.

There may be some compilers that compile to C code first. I do not know of any if you really need the code. It is not the most efficient way to do it though.

I think that is what your instructor was trying to ask you, i.e. if there is a compiler switch to generate C code.

Is there any particular reason why you need to generate C code. Creating a C interface can be useful and there are ways to do this.

Comment: If I recall correctly, Comeau's compiler can do that. I'm not sure, though.

Comment: I read that it could but the code is not humanly maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm far from a GNU expert, but I belive the compiler option would be -std=C89, to enforce compilation to follow the C90 version of the C standard (equivalent to old "ANSI C" which was released in 89, hence the C89), or -std=C99 for the C99 version of the standard.

Comment: Sure it would, it would give you a syntax error. If you used C++ unique features, then of course you wouldn't be able to compile it in C.