# Examples of C interfaces to C++ libraries?

Tags: c++, c

I'm in the process of writing a C interface to a C++ library, and I'm looking for some high-quality examples (or best practices).

So far this one seems pretty promising: http://czmq.zeromq.org/manual:czmq

Any other suggestions?

Comment: I was just going to recommend ZeroMQ, glad I read the question through :)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7953559/440558

Comment: Definitely not a duplicate of that question. This question asks for examples of how to do it well (that is, how to design the C API based on a C++ API). That other question is solely interested in the basic mechanics of doing it at all.

Answer (score 1):

You could look into the [Parma Polyhedra Library](http://bugseng.com/products/ppl) as an example of excellent C interface to a well written C++ library. PPL is a free GPL-ed software, notably used inside the [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org) compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Another high quality example is the [Open Dynamics Engine](http://opende.sourceforge.net). It has a C++ backend and a C frontend. Everything is C linkable.

- [C++ example](http://sourceforge.net/p/opende/code/1947/tree/trunk/ode/src/collision_space.cpp)
- [C example](http://sourceforge.net/p/opende/code/1947/tree/trunk/include/ode/objects.h)

Answer (score 0):

If your C++ library is written as COM on Windows. There are tools to automatically generate the C interface for it.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest [FTGL](http://ftgl.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/ftgl/trunk/demo/simple.cpp?revision=1247&view=markup) which is a C++ library providing a C interface. Here are two sample programs that achieve exactly the same thing:

- [C++ version](http://ftgl.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/ftgl/trunk/demo/simple.cpp?revision=1247&view=markup)
- [C version](http://ftgl.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/ftgl/trunk/demo/c-demo.c?revision=1247&view=markup)

Note also that FTGL uses the [pImpl paradigm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer) in order to achieve binary compatibility across versions. See [here](http://www.vnypatel.com/pimpl) why it's good.

Disclaimer: I'm an FTGL contributor.

Answer (score 0):

libGLU (OpenGL Utility Library) is partially written in C++: http://cgit.freedesktop.org/mesa/mesa/tree/src/glu

Answer (score 0):

libzmq is a kind of weird case since the low-level C API was originally meant to look like POSIX sockets, and absolutely not object-oriented (we made it more consistent and organized over time). Meanwhile the actual library is in C++.

The C++-to-C interface is in libzmq/src/zmq.cpp, and consists of a bunch of simple C functions that call the 'real' C++ code.

CZMQ on the other hand aims for something more classy, providing a simple class model with constructors, destructors, containers, private properties, etc. Nothing radical but does turn C into a much more elegant language.

I'm not sure how well the CZMQ class approach would map to a C++ API unless that API was explicitly designed to be mapped.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of most of CZMQ.