# using c class and header file in C++ application

Tags: c++, c, file-conversion

Posting a basic question about using C style `.c` and `.h` class in a C++ application.
I have a library which is meant for C but based on the documentation i can also use for C++.

Should i need to rename the two files as .cpp and .hpp before i start including them in my project ?
I tried to refer existing thread but it talks about other way crom cpp to c.

[How to convert C++ Code to C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737257/code-convert-from-c-to-c)

Answer (score 5):

No you don't. The `.h` extension is shared.

The implementation file extension depends on the compiler/IDE. For example, MSVS will compile `.c` files as C source code, and `.cpp` files as C++. That means you'll have to use

```
extern "C"
```

in the header if you use the C functionality in the C++ part of the project.

AFAIK you can compile `.c` files with `g++` as C++, so the extension change is not necessary. Or you can compile them with `gcc` and use `extern "C"` again.

Comment: As a minor note, it can be argued that it's "weird" to put `extern "C"` in a header file for a C library, since that syntax is C++. It's also possible to put `extern "C"` around the `#include` of the C header.

Comment: @unwind or surround it with `#ifdef __cplusplus`, but yes, that makes sense.

Comment: I never thought about wrapping the actual #include with an extern "C" { } block. That's pretty smart. Oh preprocessor, how can you be abused? Let me count the ways.

Comment: @NikB. - abused, indeed. Wrapping a standard header in an extern "C" block produces undefined behavior. Wrapping someone else's header in an extern "C" block may or may not work, depending on what's in the header. Imagine, for example, a header that #include's a C++ header...