# How to view the C++ program after it is converted to C (If so)?

Tags: c++, c, compilation

Correct me if I am wrong, but in one book I have read that every C++ program is converted to C while it is going through different compiling phases.

I just want to see the C code.

Can any one tell me how to view that code?

Comment: No, that is generally incorrect. It may have been so in the early days, way before standardization.

Comment: I might suggest getting a different book.

Comment: duplicate?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/737257/how-to-convert-c-code-to-c
another way (to see name mangling for exemple) should be decompile the programme to C code...

Comment: see this -  http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/convert-to-c.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Search for CFront for the answer to your question; [Wikipedia has a good summary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cfront)

C++ started out as a C code generator called CFront, but this was abandoned in 1993. Since then, all C++ compilers have been normal compilers, not C front-ends. Exceptions were the original difficulty, but there are weird corners like the subtle difference in the meaning of "void" that would be awkward too.

It is a good approach to learning C++ to think "What would the C equivalent of this be?", but you can no longer generate it from the compiler, sorry.

Edit: some people are commenting that there are products available to do what you want. I was unaware of these. I would say that although this is what you want, it probably isn't what you need. If your aim is to understand C++, read about C++.